# The set of solutions of $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^2} + 4y = 0$ is a $2$ dimensional real vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

Prove that the set of all real valued functions $y=f(x)$ satisfying $\frac{d^{2}(y)}{dx^2} + 4y = 0$ is a 2 dimensional real vector space.

It is not a homework problem, but from previous year exam.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Answer (score 2):

We know that $\sin(2x)$ and $\cos(2x)$ are two real valued functions satisfying our differential equation by observation. You can prove that these are linearly independent via the Wronskian. All that remains to be shown is that any solution to this differential equation must be a linear combination of the two we have found.

This basically looks like the examiner wanted the students to re-prove some theorem about fundamental solutions. You can probably find more details in a differential equations textbook.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I need to brush up differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

Be $\varphi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ two linearly independent solutions of your equation, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ two real numbers. Then $\frac{d^2 (\alpha \varphi(x) + \beta \psi(x))}{dx^2} + 4(\alpha \varphi(x) + \beta \psi(x)) = \frac{d^2 \alpha \varphi(x)}{dx^2} + \frac{\beta \psi(x)}{dx^2} + 4\alpha \varphi(x) + 4 \beta \psi(x)$ which is, since $\varphi \text{ and } \psi$ are solutions, equal to $0$. So, any linear combinations of those two functions is again a solution to the equation, i.e. the solutions form a $2$ dimensional vector space. Note that we made no use of the properties of the actual solutions of your equation (other than being twice differentiable) and, in fact, this generalizes pretty easily.

Comment: There are two asumptions you don't prove: that there are indeed two linearly independant solutions, and that the set of solutions in only $2$ dimensional. Actually, you only prove the set of solutions is a vector space.